# One day after putting my site online and registering it with Google I got spam mail. How?

Tags: googlebot, web-crawlers, email, spam, captcha

I put my website online yesterday and registered it with Google at the same time. Before that, I didn't even put a single link to the site anywhere online. And I don't have any email address on my site, just a mail form that is protected with ReCaptcha v. 2; see https://www.020webdesign.nl/bedrijfsinfo.php.

Still, I got a spam mail within 24 hours. :-((

I can tell that the mail was sent through the mail form, there's no doubt about that. It seems to have been entered into the form manually (even though I'm not sure about that), but how is it possible that the spammer found my site so quickly?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to keep the existence of a domain secret?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137954/is-it-possible-to-keep-the-existence-of-a-domain-secret)

Comment: One possibility I ruled out (unless something has changed in the setup).  I wondered if you had a default virtualhost of some sort that would allow a scanner to find the site.  This does not seem to be the case.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller — That's a whole lot of text and it doesn't seem to answer my question. Some more info from my side: I bought the domain name more than a year ago, with privacy protection. Since then, zero spam mails. Until yesterday, after having uploaded the site from my local machine to the server. Any additional thoughts?

Comment: If you purchased your domain name a year ago, then surely spammers have had a year to find it,  They may even have already been spamming it and you wouldn't have know about it.  It may be accidental that they came across it.  Your provider could be leaking this information.  One of their employees may be a spammer.